# How can Ruby transform a method into a symbol as argument?

Tags: ruby

The `respond_to?` method takes as argument, a method to be checked, but as a symbol.

Why as symbol? And how does ruby convert the method into a symbol?

Comment: it is not necessary that you pass `method_name` as symbol, you can also pass it as string. `.respond_to?('method_name')`.

Comment: Ok thanks. Because on codecadamy they said it takes a symbol as argument. So a string counts too ok. But why does it also take a symbol? What is this method doing with the symbol or the string (argument) ?

Comment: *"on codecadamy they said"* -- they can say whatever they want. To find the truth read the [documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Object.html#method-i-respond_to-3F).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's no magic. Methods are attached to objects by their name, which is a symbol. In fact, `Math.sin(2)` is basically a shorthand for `Math.send(:sin, 2)` ("send message `:sin` to `Math` object, with parameter `2`"). You can also access methods itself: `Math.method(:sin)` will give you the associated `Method` object (whose name, `Math.method(:sin).name`, is of course `:sin`), and `Math.methods` will list all implemented methods' names. `Math.respond_to?(:sin)` can basically be rewritten as `Math.methods.include?(:sin)` (this is simplified, as it ignores `respond_to_missing?`, but... close enough for this discussion).

Think of it this way. You go to a friend's house, and their mother answers the door. You ask, "Hello, is Tim here?" You don't need to actually drag your friend to the door and ask "Hello, is this individual here?" The name works just as well. :)

EDIT:

> Hmmm that's confusing right now for me. What does named mean exactly? I mean maybe with a little example. I call it with array.each. When does the "name" :each come into play then?

I am not sure how to explain it better. Methods have names, just like people have names. When you say `array.each`, it is sending the message `:each` to the object that is contained in the variable `array`, pretty much exactly what `array.send(:each)` would do. Methods are pieces of code attached to objects via their names: when an object receives a message, it runs the piece of code that is associated with that message.

Specifically, in the standard Ruby implementation, objects of class `Array`, when they receive the message `:each`, will invoke the C function `rb_ary_each` that is defined in the Ruby source code, and linked to the message `:each` using `rb_define_method(rb_cArray, "each", rb_ary_each, 0)` (also in the Ruby source code).

Inside Ruby, there are basically two equivalent ways to define methods. These two are equivalent:

```
class Foo
  def bar
    puts "hello"
  end
end

class Foo
  define_method(:bar) do
    puts "hello"
  end
end
```

Both of them do the same thing: associate the message `:bar` with the piece of code `do puts "hello" end`. When `:bar` is received by a `Foo` (whether through `Foo.send(:bar)` or by `Foo.bar`), this piece of code is run.

Comment: Ok thx for that explanation. That would mean that also for example .each from the Enumerable Class is also a Symbol :each ? Did I got this right?

Comment: does this http://api.rubyonrails.org/v4.2/classes/ActiveSupport/HashWithIndifferentAccess.html play any role here (specially for `symbol` and `string` acceptance? or they are 2 different concepts?

Comment: No - the method `each` from `Enumerable` *Module* is *named* `:each`. Just like Tim (the individual) is not Tim (the name), but is *called* by that name.

Comment: Hmmm that's confusing right now for me. What does named mean exactly? I mean maybe with a little example. I call it with
`array.each`. When does the "name" :each come into play then?

Comment: @Md.FarhanMemon: This question has nothing to do with `HashWithIndifferentAccess`, except for the fact that HWIA compounds the confusion many new people already have about Strings vs Symbols. Just like `1` (`Integer`) is not the same thing as `"1"` (`String`), so is `"a"` (`String`) not the same thing as `:a` (`Symbol`) - but it is easy to convert between them. Easier, in fact, because all strings can be converted to symbols, but not all strings can be converted to integers.

Comment: @Md.FarhanMemon you linked to the documentation of Ruby on Rails. Rails is a framework over Ruby. The method [`respond_to?`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Object.html#method-i-respond_to-3F) is a core Ruby method defined in class [`Object`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Object.html) and it works with or without Rails.

Comment: ohh, I thought under the hood, the fact that `:method` is replaceable to `method` is having the same logic as HWIA.

Comment: Thx so much @Md.FarhanMemon for helping me out here. It's much clearer now. I will check your answer as answer. Have a good one :)

Comment: @Md.FarhanMemon In a way, you're correct. Most method-handling functions will accept names as both strings and symbols. `Math.method("sin")` returns the same result as `Math.method(:sin)` does. Symbols and strings are different things as far as Ruby is concerned, but those functions handle both, indeed like HWIA does. But saying HWIA plays a role here because of this similar behaviour is like saying cars play a role in bank safes because they both use keys. :)

Comment: ok, a must mention, like your examples `is like saying`, that adds much more to the answer, lol..